# netinstall media of CentOS 6.4 is broken?

Tags: centos, partition

I couldn't find a way to customize the partition schema during installation of CentOS 6.4, all these 3 options lead me directly to the "confirm disk change" screen.

[image]

Was it configured to be so? 'caue I saw a line says `The default layout is suitable for most users`.

If not, how can I setup my own partitioning schema?

Comment: TUI installer does not has such option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TUI installer does not has such option to customize partition layout, you can only customize partition layout in GUI installer. See the following note in RHEL installation guide.

> ### Important — Installing in text mode
>
> If you install Red Hat Enterprise Linux in text mode, you can only use the default partitioning schemes described in this section. You cannot add or remove partitions or file systems beyond those that the installer automatically adds or removes. If you require a customized layout at installation time, you should **perform a graphical installation over a VNC connection or a kickstart installation**.
>   Furthermore, advanced options such as LVM, encrypted filesystems, and resizable filesystems are available only in graphical mode and kickstart.

[RHEL 6 Installation Guide](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/index.html) - [16.15. Disk Partitioning Setup](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-diskpartsetup-ppc.html)